# What space suit is this?

Tags: soyuz-spacecraft, spacesuits, identify-this-object, jaxa, roscosmos

[image: Astronaut Norishige Kanai (Left) in space suit]

I recently saw this picture, and it puzzles me as to what they are wearing. At first thought, I imagined that they would be space suits. But, they went in a Soyuz craft, and the suits for a Soyuz don't look like that, so either they are new spacesuits, or they are wearing something different. What are they?

Comment: Can you provide your source for this image?

Comment: It appears to be just a thermal overgarment.